# Why an uninstalled module is still importable in Python

Tags: python

I want to get rid of a module in Python and I use the "pip uninstall " command. However, for some reason the module is still importable! I am using VS code on a Mac OS. Here is the screenshot of the code:

[image]

As you can see, the yellow warning says the polars package is not installed (because I already excuted the uninstall command) however in the cell below it, the polars module has been imported succesfully! Can anyone explain what is happening and how can I completely remove the module so it is not importable anymore?

Comment: Are you sure your kernel is using the same `pip` as the one you're using to uninstall the package? `!pip` gives you system pip. Try again using `%pip`

Comment: Did you run the `import polars` cell after uninstalling it or is it the older output that is shown in your image?

Comment: There are multiple things which might be going on here. One is that the `pip` command on your system is not for the same version (or the same installation) of Python as you are running. Another is that you have your own file named `polars.py` and that's what you're importing.

Comment: @AbirbhavG. %pip solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1 -Try to use %pip, maybe you are using virtual machines and %pip is  'magic' command that actually runs commands to uninstall the same package across all machines in the cluster

2- Script wrappers installed by python setup.py develop.

You need to remove all files manually, and also undo any other stuff that installation did manually.

If you don't know the list of all files, you can reinstall it with the --record option, and take a look at the list this produces. To record list of installed files, you can use:

```
$ python setup.py install --record files.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is restart your kernel.
Use this button to restart the kernel
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Q6L.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).